# jQuery Hover to scroll on another element

Tags: javascript, jquery, scroll, hover

(Edit: I found the problem...it has something to do with the css styling of the elements but I still don't know why, the jQuery below is still wrong but the problem stems from css.))

I have 2 html elements.

Short term goal:

I want to hover over a word in element #1 and in element #2, have a specific item in a list show up (doesn't have to be a list but thought that it would be easier).

This is the jQuery code that I have so far, it ought to go to the 3rd list item:

```
$( document ).ready(function() {
$(".test").hover(function(){
    $("#list").animate({
    scrollTop: $("#list li:nth-child(2)").position().top
}, 500);
});
})
```

[Here is the jsfiddle!](https://jsfiddle.net/fiatlucy/hw3wh0e6/)

What I want to eventually do:

When I hover over "HOVER TEST WORDS ONE" it will go to list item#1, when I hover over "HOVER TEST WORDS TWO" it will go to list item#2, etc.

Answer (score 0):

NOTE: In your jFiddle you do not have JQuery enabled but I dont know if you are using that to develop.

Here is my solution:

```
    $( document ).ready(function() {

    $(".test").hover(function(){
        $("#mis").animate({
        scrollTop: $("#list li:nth-child(2)").position().top
    }, 500);

    });
});
```

You need to change #list to #mis as you cannot scroll a list. You must scroll a section.

Comment: @fiat.lucy Hi, [here is my JSFiddle of this working](https://jsfiddle.net/jagoldsmith/LabesvfL/) Comment if you need more help.

Comment: Your edit is not very specific. Why do you think the problem stems from CSS?